# When will the 2015 Community Moderator Election begin?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I saw in the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) that the last two elections were in February, So may I ask If there is any news about 2015 Community Moderator Election?

Comment: Take a look at the other dates.  There's no set time when the election period runs.  Generally, it runs when Stack Overflow needs more moderators; since that hasn't seem to have occurred yet, it's not active.

Comment: Yes I saw them before asking the question, that's why I said "the last two elections" ! Thanks anyway

Comment: You are assuming there will be one. Elections are not held to schedule - they are held when they are _needed_. For example - there were 2 elections in 2011, as the site needed more moderators.

Comment: @Oded thanks for the explanations, I am a little new so once i saw that there was at least one election per year I thought that its something which should happen every year! but now its clear to me, thanks :)

Comment: @Oded Is it normal to mark that as duplicate even if it was before the election?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There isn't any election currently planned for 2015. The last couple of elections were triggered by departures of existing moderators, along with a steady growth in flags.

While we've had changes in activity level of current moderators throughout the year, I'm not aware of any outright departures. Also, the flag volume has been highly variable throughout the last year as various things have been experimented with.

A large chunk of flags are now being handled by the community in review, and SE is experimenting with hiding certain flags from moderators for various durations. Better flag-handling tools are also being tested, in an attempt to let fewer people handle more flags efficiently.

Therefore, it's hard to predict when more moderators might be needed. We typically only find out about a moderator election a day or two before the rest of the site does, so they might start tomorrow or we might not have any in 2015.

Comment: Why are moderators only promoted when *needed*? Is there any reason why we can’t just keep promoting new ones? I’m sure that one or another moderator would welcome others taking away some of their work (moderators should be allowed to have lifes too, in my opinion). And I don’t see a problem with having too many moderators either. They are community-elected after all.

Comment: @poke - I've talked about this before in more detail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185247/are-stack-overflow-mods-spending-enough-time-evaluating-each-flag/185264#185264 , but simply adding a pile of moderators isn't a great solution. We don't want the site to be run by a cabal of superpowered users, but instead to make sure that the community can manage itself. Figuring out ways of letting the community handle flagged posts is a better long-term strategy than just pouring on moderators.

Comment: @poke Too many managers ruin a product.

Comment: Ah. So my plans of attaining world domination through massive abuse of the powers of a StackOverflow moderator must be put on hold simply because not enough people are **quitting**?!? Nuts. There goes another perfectly good nefarious plan down the drain... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis Unless, perish the thought, one of the existing mods has a terrible accident........

Comment: @DavidG - well...I mean...world domination, yes. Bending people to my twisted will - yes. Recklessly unleashing the forces of evil upon a defenseless planet - goes without saying. But, y'know, *hurting people*? No, I'm afraid that's a thought I'm not prepared to entertain...

Comment: @BobJarvis Hurting people?! I never suggested that, must be your sick mind.... :P

Comment: @DavidG - so not hurting people is OK? Great! Then I'll move forward with my nefarious plan. (*grabs loudspeaker*) ATTENTION ALL MINIONS! BRING FORTH THE PLANET-RUPTURING DEATH RAY MACHINES, PLEASE!! Hmmm...now where *did* I put the key for the planet-rupturing death ray machines..? Oh dear, oh dear - delays, delays...